# Replace a variable in JSON object

Tags: javascript

I'm writing JavaScript code in which I want to replace a string in JSON object and my code is as below.

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "name is $name",
  "work": "$name is doctor",
  "maritial status": "unmarried"
};

obj = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key, index) {
  return (obj[key].includes('$name')) ? obj[key].replace('$name', 'John'): obj[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Here I want to replace `$name` with `John` and print the JSON, but unfortunately, this is printing only the values like below instead of the whole JSON.

`["name is John", "John is doctor", "unmarried"]`

Where I am going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a transformed object as the result, either assign the changed value to the original object:

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "name is $name",
  "work": "$name is doctor",
  "maritial status": "unmarried"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (obj[key].includes('$name')) {
    obj[key] = obj[key].replace('$name', 'John');
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Or use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to map to a new object:

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "name is $name",
  "work": "$name is doctor",
  "maritial status": "unmarried"
};
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => [key, val.replace('$name', 'John')])
);

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You keep mentioning JSON but what you have is a *JavaScript* object. JSON is a string. So it would be much easier for you to *keep* it as a string, do a simple replace on the name, and *then* parse it to an object.

```js
const json = '{"name":"name is $name","work":"$name is doctor", "maritial status":"unmarried"}';

const updated = json.replaceAll('$name', 'John');

console.log(JSON.parse(updated));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `Object.entries` method or other object methods to solve your problem one of them might be ...

```
let obj = {
  "name": "name is $name",
  "work": "$name is doctor",
  "maritial status": "unmarried"
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(item => {
  if ((obj[item[0]].includes('$name'))) {
    item[1] = item[1].replace("$name", "John");
    obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  }
})
console.log(obj);
```